# Converter data c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Boas pessoal eu estou com um problema no meu código. eu na minha base de dados tenho um campo do tipo `date` só que depois ao chama-lo para o programa ele passa me também as hora , fica algo do genero: 18-03-2015 00:00:00.
O que eu queria era so a parte da data e antes de vir aqui experimentei isto

```cs
DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DATA"]);
                DateTime dataOnly = data.Date;
                string dataFinal = dataOnly.ToString("d");
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

E isto fez exatamente o que eu queria porém no programa que eu tenho que fazer ele só insere a ultima data.
Vou deixar aqui em baixo o código e uma imagem para vocês perceberem melhor

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace experiencia
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SageNGCOApi.BaseNext SageNextAPI = new SageNGCOApi.BaseNext();
            SageNextAPI.PercIni = "C:\\ProgramData\\Sage\\2070\\Next\\";
            SageNextAPI.PercLOG = "C:\\ProgramData\\Sage\\2070\\Next\\";
            SageNextAPI.Empresa = "FDISQL";
            SageNextAPI.Password = "teste";
            SageNextAPI.Login = "teste";
            int resultado;
            resultado = SageNextAPI.Iniciar();
            if (resultado != 0) // 0: Sucesso
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro ao iniciar Sage Next API");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SUCESSO!");
            }

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Hugo\Desktop\teste\config.ini");
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(text);
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * from my_cab", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SageNGCOApi.DocumentoComercial documento = new SageNGCOApi.DocumentoComercial();
                documento.ActivarGrelhasDesconto = false;
                documento.ActivarLinhasBonus = true;
                documento.ActivarLinhasPreco = true;


                DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DATA"]);
                DateTime dataOnly = data.Date;
                string dataFinal = dataOnly.ToString("d");
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));




                documento.cab.Sector = Convert.ToString(reader["SETOR"]);
                documento.cab.TipoDocumento = Convert.ToString(reader["DOCUMENTO"]);
                documento.cab.Serie = 1;
                documento.cab.Data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                documento.cab.NossoNoDocumento = 0; // 0 lê numerador
                documento.cab.Terceiro = Convert.ToString(reader["TERCEIRO"]);
                documento.cab.Moeda = "EUR";
                documento.cab.RegimeIva = documento.Cliente.REGIVA;
                documento.Origem = SageNGCOApi.eOrigemDocumento.NaoAplicavel;



                SqlCommand cmd_1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MY_LIN WHERE REGISTO=@reg", conn);
                cmd_1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", reader["REGISTO"]);
                SqlDataReader le = cmd_1.ExecuteReader();

                while (le.Read())
                {

                    SageNGCOApi.DocumentosGcLin linha = new SageNGCOApi.DocumentosGcLin();

                    linha.TipoDeLinha = 1; // 1-Movimento; 2-Abatimento; 3-Despesa; 4-Informativo
                    linha.Armazem = Convert.ToString(le["ARMAZEM"]);
                    linha.Artigo = Convert.ToString(le["ARTIGO"]);
                    linha.Unidade = Convert.ToString(le["UNIDADE"]);
                    linha.PrecoUnitario = Convert.ToDecimal(le["PRECO"]);
                    linha.Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(le["VALOR"]);
                    linha.Quantidade = Convert.ToDecimal(le["QNT"]);
                    linha.Desconto = Convert.ToString(le["DESCONTO"]);
                    linha.TaxaDesconto = Convert.ToDecimal(le["T_DESC"]);
                    documento.SugereValoresLin(linha, false, true, true, false, false, false, true);
                    documento.AdicionaLinha(linha);
                }


               if (documento.Validar() == 0)
                {
                    if (documento.Inserir() == 0)
                        if (resultado == 0) // 0: Sucesso
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Documento inserido com sucesso!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao inserir documento: " + documento.UltimaMensagem());
                        }
                }
               else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Erro ao validar documento: " + documento.UltimaMensagem());
               }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu usar a data como a data atual `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` ele funciona e insere as datas todas porem se eu usar a data como a data que vem da base de dados e que depois converti ele só insere a ultima. Deixo umas imagens para perceberem melhor e se souberem agradecia que me ajudasse. Obrigado!

[image: Data Atual]

[image: Data que vem da base de dados convertida]

Comment: Olhando esse código não consegui achar o problema. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Já tentou um debug?

Comment: Pois, eu tbm não sei qual é o problema e já passei horas nisto tentando encontrar uma solução.
O que é um debug? Desculpe mas ainda não conheço muito de c#

Comment: Não vejo onde você usa a variável `dataOnly` e/ou `dataFinal`, pois aqui: `documento.cab.Data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");` é usando o tempo atual. Seria porque é o programa que está sendo mostrado primerio? Quando *não* funciona, é quando tem algo assim: `document.cab.Data = dataFinal;`?

Comment: E a função `documento.Inserir()`, é muito complexo? Considere criando um [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) se for necessário.

Comment: Afinal, o que você está tentando fazer? Explique com poucas palavras, sua pergunta está muito complexa e pouco legível. Seja mais claro.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar DataSet no lugar do DataReader?

Comment: Aprenda aqui como debugar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zoIzC_nmxs

Answer (score 3):

Simplesmente escreva

```
NomeVariavel.ToShortDateString();
```

Não tem porquê dificultar quando se há funcionalidades nativas para essas situações.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você quer é apenas imprimir a data na tela, tente assim:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DATA"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Dessa forma você mostra o valor de data que veio do BD sem o horário.

Comment: Mas o problema não é mostrar sem a parte do horário isso eu já consegui fazer o problema é que se eu fizer a conversão depois o programa não funciona corretamente como pode ver nas 2 imagens de cima da consola, e é isso que eu não percebo porque dá erro.

Comment: @Hugo, bom dia.Não entendi sua explicação. Pelo que vejo nas duas saídas, quando você usa o Now, ele repete e é isso que você não quer, certo? Quando você não utiliza o Now aí ele printa as data corretas, do seu banco. Isso é que eu estou vendo nas saidas que você postou no post inicial. Qual erro a aplicação gera?

Comment: @Hugo, olá lendo agora com mais detalhes entendi. O que eu comentei, leia-se ao contrário. O problema pode estar em seus métodos Inserir() e Validar(). Dê uma olhada com detalhes nele ou poste aqui para fazermos uma análise melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [TryParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) para fazer isso seu código ficaria assim.

```
DateTime valor;
DateTime.TryParseExact(reader["DATA"], "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out valor);

    ....
    documento.cab.Serie = 1;
    documento.cab.Data = valor;

    ....
```